# Replacement DVD drive for MacBook Pro

Tags: hardware, optical-drive

Howdy. I have a MacBook Pro 15" (MB133LL/A) with a Matsushita UJ-867 DVD drive. The DVD drive is failing and I'm looking for a replacement.

Are there any other supported drives for this machine than the UJ-867?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some variations in the drives supplied in Apple's products. For example, often Apple will have multiple suppliers for a part, and products often have hardware options. As such there will be other drives that are supported.

I find sites such as [iFixIt](http://www.ifixit.com/) or [Other World Computing](http://eshop.macsales.com/) that are targeting DIY repair and upgrades are helpful as they provide a guide to which parts are compatible with various Mac and MacBook models.

Here are some results for your MacBook Pro:

- [15" MacBook Pro optical drives at iFixIt](http://www.ifixit.com/Mac-Parts/MacBook-Pro-15%22-Model-A1260#0-Optical+Drives)
- [15" MacBook Pro SuperDrives at OWC](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/superdrive/MacBook_Pro_15)